# Pandas read_csv skiprows for large files take too much time to load data

Tags: pandas, dataset, large-data

I have a large file (e.g 20Gb) i want to read some samples of that data by skip rows 
but it takes too much time to skip lines and read a few rows

```
pd.read_csv(dataset_path, skiprows=100000000, nrows=100, encoding="utf-16")
```

is skipping lines in a file get too much time? isn't a way to skip lines faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try of reading chunk by chunk rather than skipping rows

Read the chunk which you prefer to have

```
iter_csv = pd.read_csv(='sample.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=10000,error_bad_lines=False)
data = pd.concat ([chunk.loc[chunk['Column_name']==1)] for chunk in iter_csv] )
```

Comment: what is the difference between this method to make this reading faster